# How to print an array of array in a formatted way?

Tags: scala

```
val k = Array(Array("s", "2", "20"),Array("sw", "3", "3"))
```

How do i convert into a string of the form :

```
"[[s,2,20],[sw,3,3]]"
```

Comment: Array is going to have only 3 elements always?

Comment: @RamanMishra yes. i got the correct answer btw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [mkString](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#mkString(start:String,sep:String,end:String):String) method of `Array` class:

```
println(k.map(_.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
object DemoAbc extends App {
      val k = Array(Array("s", "2", "20"), Array("sw", "3", "3"))

      val r = k.map(_.toList).toList

      println(r.toString.replaceAll("List", "").replaceAll("\\(", "[").replaceAll("\\)", "]"))

    }
```

Comment: what's wrong I would love to improve please let me know